# Custom template is not showing on page in joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have created a menu for the main menu and attached a self made component to it and selected a new template from the drop-down for that menu and saved it when i open the menu on browser then it opens but when i enable SEF setting for seo it doesn't show the new template.

I am explaining you my problem with example:-
*firstly we created a component named as store
*then adding this component from admin creates a new menu in components named product store and this creates a menu item type store under which sub menu product store which we select as menu item item type, this automatically connects our component to the menu item.
*finally save the menu item and creates the menu in the main menu name product store menu or the title provided to the menu.

this is how we have installed the complete component. now the problem is :-
when we click the menu without
sef settings disabled
the item id which it displays is 414
which is the actual id shown in admin
but
when the sef setting is enabled
the item id which we get is 401
401 is not in the database

Answer (score 0):

Then most likely that page is also assigned with another menu item ID. Review your menu structure and check if that page doesn't have several menu items assigned to it (this can cause many other problems by the way).